# Right usage of veranda

Tags: word-usage

Can you please anybody give an example for right usage of veranda. I go through Google and Wikipedia, its not mentioned as proper in ***Usage***

Comment: Also, *verandah*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veranda.

Comment: You walk out on it and lay on a lounge chair.  If you're smart you leave your iPad inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He placed the chair, facing out from the veranda," would be an example of its correct usage.

It is just a noun (more generally used as a count noun that requires an article) used to describe a section - usually roofed - connected to the front of the house. Also, porch may sometimes be used in its stead.

[image]